# Automatic Field Update/ Calculated Field

Tags: mysql, count, calculated-columns

I've been trying to find out if the following scenario is possible, I'll do my best to describe!

```
Table - trespondent

id, company, staff, responses


Table - tresults

id, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5
```

Ideally, what I'm looking to do is automatically UPDATE the `responses` field in `trespondent` each time an `id` is entered into the `tresults` table that matches the `id` in `trespondent`.

Effectively, the `responses` field gives a running `COUNT` of the number of responses for that `id` in `tresults`.

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be possible by using triggers

here is the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html

and here is a example and more explanation: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers

Answer (score 1):

How about, when you actually need the number of responses, do:

```
SELECT count(responses)
FROM trespondent trp
JOIN tresults trs USING(id)
WHERE trp.id = some-id
```

Comment: why this first part in where clause? `trp.id = trs.id` isn't it unneccessary? you have the join using id

Comment: Obviously, not a problem to do a simple collect.  For onerous reasons I won't go into, I need the data in the trespondents table....  Thanks however.

Answer (score 0):

Either perform all inserts (and deletes) into tresults via stored procedures that implement the logic you've described, or read up on [triggers in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html), and place a trigger on the tresults table that 'does the magic'